# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Verify that the instance name is correct

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

```
string hashPassword = func.security(txtPAssword);
        int userId = func.AuthenticateUser(txtuserName.Text, hashPassword);
        switch (userId)
        {
            case -1:
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid UserName/Password";
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                break;

            default:
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtuserName.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), false, Session["Roles"].ToString(), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

                if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                {
                    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtuserName.Text, false));
                Session["userName"] = txtuserName.Text;
                break;
```

I have already checked my sqlconfiguration and all the stuff but it does not fix
 Exception coming after this line Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtuserName.Text, false));
 it shows me this screen
[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adWHs.png)

[This is Web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSsia.png)

Comment: `AuthenticateUser` function access database right? can you show this function code

Comment: what is Zeeshan? is it your server name? is it default instance?

Comment: Sepupic this server name

Comment: Saif nothing wrong with that function i guess